# Texmaker on Mac is lagging

Tags: texmaker

So since yesterday, I've had this problem:
When I'm typing in my .tex file, suddenly, Texmaker has become very laggy. Both with typing and with selecting text.
So I've tried restarting, that didn't help. I thought that maybe my document was too big (even though it is only 68 lines), so, I tried opening a smaller document (only 20 lines), and it too was laggy when typing. I opened a new document, and it seemed fine, until it too got laggy after typing for 3 seconds. Even with complete gibberish (just a few random letters on each line), and without turning it into a file or even naming and saving it, it didn't remove the lag.
But: I just downloaded a random file of 173 lines, including ones containing entire paragraphs, and it works fine.. No lag whatsoever. Any idea as to what might be my problem?

Comment: Could you please provide any further information? Because "it doesn't work" is not a very exact description of a problem. Maybe you can provide console output, log files or backtraces of the program.

Comment: Well, that's just the case. I can't provide any files to back it up. It's just.. lag. Other applications don't suffer from it, and like I stated, it occurs in new documents, whereas a certain large file doesn't have any problems whatsoever.

Comment: You're probably not using the [good version](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#macosx).

Comment: I know this question is on hold, but I am also encountering this issue, so its not just an isolated case.